# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'FeedParser'

Tags: swift, optional

Насколько я понял нужно как-то то избавиться от проверки на `nil`. Но не пойму как в конкретном случае это сделать, и как можно изменить код чтобы уйти от этой ошибки.

```
    func loadArticles() {
    let feedURL = URL(string: self.feedURL)!
    if let parser = FeedParser(URL: feedURL) { // or FeedParser(data: data)
        // Parse asynchronously, not to block the UI.
        parser.parseAsync(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)) { (result) in
            // Do your thing, then back to the Main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // ..and update the UI
                switch result {
                case let .atom(feed): break       // Atom Syndication Format Feed Model
                case let .rss(feed):        // Really Simple Syndication Feed Model
                    print("rss obtained!")
                    self.articlesArray = feed.items!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case let .json(feed):       // JSON Feed Model
                    print("json obtained!")
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("error parsing feed URL")
    }
}
```

Comment: Задайте ваш вопрос на обычном Stackoverflow. На данном форуме вопросы задаются на русском

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так вам нужно сделать, у вас проверка на `nil` вот тут `if let parser = FeedParser(URL: feedURL) {` всегда будет `true`. Проверйте вместо етого `feedURL`

```
func loadArticles() {    
    let feedURL = URL(string: self.feedURL)
    if let url = feedURL {
        let parser = FeedParser(URL: feedURL) // or FeedParser(data: data)
        // Parse asynchronously, not to block the UI.
        parser.parseAsync(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)) { (result) in
            // Do your thing, then back to the Main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // ..and update the UI
                switch result {
                case let .atom(feed): break       // Atom Syndication Format Feed Model
                case let .rss(feed):        // Really Simple Syndication Feed Model
                    print("rss obtained!")
                    self.articlesArray = feed.items!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                case let .json(feed):       // JSON Feed Model
                    print("json obtained!")
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("error parsing feed URL")
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо. да оказалось всё проще чем я думал) Ещё xcode говорит нужно поставить восклицательный знак `let parser = FeedParser (URL: feedURL!) `